# Segmentation fault while inserting a node into a skiplist

Tags: c, skip-lists

I am trying to insert some elements on a skiplist

```
typedef struct skiplist {

struct node * header;
struct node * termnode;

}skiplist;

typedef struct node
{
int key;
entr value;
struct node *next[MaxLevel];
}node;
```

in which the nodes are sorted by their key.However,when i try to insert a node with a bigger key than the previous one i get a segfault and i found that it happens in the insert function

```
void insert(list l,int skey,entr newvalue) {
nod update[MaxLevel-1];
for(i=0;i<=MaxLevel-1;i++) {
    update[i]=(nod)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}

nod x=l->header;
for(i=MaxLevel-1;i>=0;i--) {
    while (x->next[i]->key<skey) {
        x=x->next[i];
    }
    update[i]=x;    
}
x=x->next[0];
if(x->key=skey) x->value=copyvalue(newvalue);
else
{
    int lvl=randl();
    x=makenode(l,lvl,skey,newvalue);
    for(i=0;i<=lvl;i++) {

        x->next[i]=update[i]->next[i];
        update[i]->next[i]=x;
    }
}
printf("\ninserted to list\n");
}
```

in

```
while (x->next[i]->key<skey)
```

because

```
next[i]
```

is NULL.
I can't understand why this is happening and any help would be appreciated

Comment: Start checking your array boundaries. There are several questionable, and one clearly-wrong limiting conditions. Your for-loop : `i<=MaxLevel-1` as a conditional, where `update` is declared as `update[MaxLevel-1]` introduces a guaranteed-reach beyond your declared size, as that array is reachable only from `0..(MaxLevel-2)` as subscript indexes. I.e. that conditional should be `i<MaxLevel-1`. therefore, you're code invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: i edited the array boundaries but i keep getting the error.it seems like that `x=x->next[0]` is NULL too